# what are the principles of good design with Wolfram Language a la Zen of Python?

Tags: language-design

The Zen of Python — is a list of 19 general truths for Python design principles.
( https://medium.com/@Pythonidaer/a-brief-analysis-of-the-zen-of-python-2bfd3b76edbf )

Comment: What are your thoughts?  If ever a question was "opinion-based," this is it!

Comment: Python and Mathematica are at complete opposite of the spectrum on #13 in your list. `There should be one — and preferably only one — obvious way to do it` In Mathematica, if one can't do it in 10 different ways, it means one is not yet very good in Mathematica :)